# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, jersey

I have a Jersey Server, where I send an `OutputStream` of data on `GET` request. The data stream will be consumed on the client side. I am getting the following error on the server side:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream, genericType=class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.
```

I also get `HTTP Status 500: Internal server error` on the client side. As of now, I am using `Postman` to test the application. I have already searched web for the answer, however, I could not find anything substantial. Please let me know if you have any solutions. Thanks in advance!

Here is the server side code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;

@Path("/test")
public class TestDataStreamResource {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response Test() throws IOException {
        QueryEngineHTTP q = null;
        ResultSet results = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



        String query = "SELECT * FROM<" + "http://localhost:8890/sparql/lubm" + "> WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 10";
        q = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://localhost:8890/sparql/", query);
        results = q.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(baos, results);
        return Response.ok(baos, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: How does it make sense to send a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?  The client wants the data, not an object with which to write data.  Instead, send `baos.toByteArray()` (a `byte[]` containing the bytes written so far).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I am such a doofus, forgot to pay attention to such a trivial mistake. Thanks for the input.